# PHP sperate geojson from mysql by comma

Tags: php

Below i have what my php and geojson is looking like. I want to separate them by comma except for the last "while query" for it work with leaflet. I've tried just to echo a comma behind the $data['geojson'] but it then also echos a comma at the end which makes it not work. Right now its working as long as there is only one row in the database.

The geojson is stored inside the column „geojson“ and each geojson line has its own row

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `polygons` ORDER BY id";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);

    $check = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($check > 0){
        echo '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[';
        
    while($data= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    
    echo $data["geojson"];
    
    
    }
    echo "]}";
```

GEOJSON:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[9.836037,54.92779],[9.79818,54.93067],[9.769213,54.924124],[9.745858,54.906048],[9.796566,54.879997],[9.860286,54.89273],[9.837761,54.925973],[9.836037,54.92779]]]}}


{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[9.855609,54.956418],[9.867858,54.923851],[9.971178,54.943613],[9.92426,54.969291],[9.855609,54.956418]]]}}]}
```

Comment: It's unclear. Is one of those GeoJSON samples the content from your database? Or both? Or neither? Or is that the expected result you want the PHP to generate? Please explain properly what you're showing us.

Comment: `it then also echos a comma at the end which makes it not work`...you could always just trim that (if you build up a string gradually rather than immediately echoing it). But better to do what Barmar suggests and build the data structure properly in PHP, and then just encode it all at the end - that way PHP's built-in JSON library will take care of all the niceties of the formatting for you, with no potential for errors.

Comment: It’s what the data[geojson] contains.

Comment: So those two lines are all in one row in your table? Or it's from two rows. Edit the question to clarify it properly, don't just hide info in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry my mistakes - but each json line is inside its own row then inside geojson column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create JSON by concatenating or echoing strings. Create an array with all the data, then use `json_encode()`.

Since the table column contains `JSON`, you need to decode it before pushing it onto the result array. Otherwise it will be encoded twice.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `polygons` ORDER BY id";

$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);

$check = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($check > 0){
    $array = ['type' => 'FeatureCollection', 'features' => []];
    while($data= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $array['features'][] = json_decode($data['geojson'], true);
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: Does Stack Overflow need this advice to be posted once again?

Comment: This is a little differen from the usual, because of the need to decode the JSON in the `geojson` column before pushing it onto the array.

Comment: thats why i could not find anything on it and had to ask but thanks! @Barmar

Comment: Because Stack Overflow has literally millions of pages, it is very hard to ask a unique, narrow, on-topic question in 2022.  Here's the condensed solution: https://3v4l.org/uPnIC